# Export different excel for each iteration in the for loop (store different matrix for each iteration)

Tags: loops, for-loop, export, iteration, store

I would like to export excel file for each iteration in the for loop or store different matrix for each iteration.

what I used in the code is that,

```
  ##code  
for s=10:10:100
  'my code for make a specific scope from raw data'
  ...
% result is the storage space
numData=size('from the scope');
result=zeros(numData,25); 
%calculate within the scope
  for i=1:numData
  data_new_x = Scope(:,i);
  data_mean_x=mean(data_new_x); %mean x
  result(i,1)=data_mean_x;
  ...
  end
end
```

So, by changing the variable s, the output matrix, result, will be different. I would like to store this results for each iteration.

If you have have good idea to solve this problem, please let me know!